# How to display text in more than one language on a Thymeleaf based web page

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, thymeleaf

I have a small Spring based application with Thymeleaf HTML templates. My web pages should be localized dependent on the browser locale.

Therefore I use `messages.properties` files to localize all my static text on the web pages like this in my Thymeleaf templates:

```
th:text="#{message_identifier}"
```

Right know three languages are supported: English, German, and Arabic.

- messages.properties
- messages_de.properties
- messages_ar.properties

Since Arabic might not be readable for some people even to identify labels on a login page I would like to show a balloon or alternative text in English when hovering over the (Arabic) text on the page.

How can I access localized messages in English (or any other specific language) even if a different locale is set by the browser for the current request?

Comment: Do you want to have something like `<label for="username" th:title="#{message_identifier}" th:text="#{message_identifier}">Username</label>` or `<label for="username" th:title="#{hint_message_identifier}" th:text="#{message_identifier}">Username</label>`?

Comment: Yes, that is almost what I want, but how can I tell thymeleaf to use the English message for `th:title="#{message_identifier}"` and the browsers language message for `th:text="#{message_identifier}"`? Your second solution would mean I have to copy the English messages (with a `hint_` prefix). But if they are only present in the default messages.properties file is should be okay.

Comment: If you can live with `<label for="username" th:title="#{hint_message_identifier}" th:text="#{message_identifier}">Username</label>`, which produces something like `<label for="username" title="Please provide your registered username">اسم المستخدم</label>`, you can keep all your messages in a separate file (`hints.properties`), which is not localized (in single language only). This would be the easiest option. Alternatively, you can extend the default Thymeleaf dialect and expose the `getMessage(String, Object[], Locale)` method from the `MessageSource` interface.

Comment: For me the first option is a good solution. Even if this means that I have another set of messages with the tool tips. But the good thing is - like you mentioned in your example - I can have more user friendly messages like _"Please provide your registered username"_ instead of only a plain _"Username"_.

Comment: Yes, that is how we run our application, although we have exposed the full `MessageSource` to our views as well.